# Compiler Error in Delphi10.2 when adding custom JAR libraries to Android project

Tags: android, delphi, compiler-errors, google-cloud-messaging, delphi-10.2-tokyo

i got a problem with adding JAR file to my project, i copied both files `google-play-services-gcm-7.0.0.jar` and `google-play-services-gcm-7.0.0.dex.jar` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\lib\android\debug` , in project manager,in Libraries i pressed revert system files to default, now when i compile i get this error..  , how to fix this ?

PS : i'm following this tutorial : `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ncuzTy03iE`

`[Exec Error] The command "PATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\InterBase\redist\InterBaseXE7\IDE_spoof;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\AL-Busaidi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\AL-Busaidi\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps & "D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat" --dex --output="C:\Users\AL-Busaidi\Downloads\fontes-push4\Mobile\Android\Debug\classes.dex" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\android-support-v4.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\cloud-messaging.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\fmx.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-analytics-v2.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-billing.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-licensing.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services-gcm-7.0.0.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services.dex.jar" " exited with code 2.`

when i diable both `google-play-services-gcm-7.0.0.jar` and `google-play-services-gcm-7.0.0.dex.jar` from libraries it compiles successfully.

Comment: Exit code 2 means duplicate symbols in one or more dex's. I'd say remove google-play-services.dex.jar from the Libraries node under Android in the Project Manager

Answer (score 0):

try to run

```
"D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat" --dex --output="C:\Users\AL-Busaidi\Downloads\fontes-push4\Mobile\Android\Debug\classes.dex" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\android-support-v4.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\cloud-messaging.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\fmx.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-analytics-v2.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-billing.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-licensing.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services-gcm-7.0.0.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services.dex.jar"
```

to know with error you have :)